# show value in one variable for distinct values in another variable in R

Tags: r

I'm actually a very noob in coding but want to go ahead learning and I did't find the answer for my problem searching on side. So I hope to get an anwer by just asking you...
I have a dataframe with >50.000 observations and about 30 variables.
I found that in variable "ID" I have 204 distinct values (these are the IDs of the participants in the study). For every ID there is of course only one age (and of course only one birth date, sex and so on). I want to know the value for the second variable for every participant.

I tried different combinations of table (), distinct(), filter(), and "group_by" to simply show me value of "age", or "sex" for the different participants.. but I am actually lost. I also thought about creating a new df but I'm convinced there is a smarter and easy way. It's just that alone I don't find it.

I tried the answer for another question on this website ("R list all distinct values for each value of another variable") that would look like
df%>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise( values= paste(age,collapse=","))
but it gives me back not only one time but lots of times the age. And in the end I'd like to use this code to go ahead and also calculate the mean age and so on.

Can you please tell me what to do or just show me a link to where the way was described before?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Perhaps `distinct(df, ID, age)`? Or you can use `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(1)` to just get the first row for each participant. It is really hard to help you without a simple example of your data and the code you have tried so far. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info on how to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: omg, that was just too easy. I am a little embaressed. Thank you so much, Axeman. Now I have this: distinct(fd, ID, age)
       ID                         age
1          1.0099e+11    94
1565       1.0099e+11    93
3375       1.0099e+11    97
5143       1.0099e+11    89
6919       1.0099e+11    92
9152       1.0099e+11    82
10735      1.0099e+11    64
12908      1.0099e+11    87
14256      1.0099e+11    94
15847      1.0099e+11    89  and it looks good. How can I now get the mean for the age?

Comment: `distinct(df, ID, age) %>% pull(age) %>% mean()` or `distinct(df, ID, age) %>% summarise(mean_age = mean(age))`

Answer (score -1):

We can still use `group_by` function in conjunction with `unique()` like below:

```
mtcars[,c('hp','cyl','gear')] %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(gear=unique(gear))
```

If you change `group_by(cyl)` to `group_by(hp)`, the result from `unique(gear)` will change accordingly (8 rows ->24 rows).

Comment: @Gregor Thomas The unique() from base library does work on my side, even though the by parameter is not mentioned. It is not quite clear from your writing that which variable you want to get unique value, and which variable is your group?

Comment: @Gregor Thomas Please don't rush. That is because there are duplicate values in other columns of `mtcars` . If for each of your `ID`, there is only one `age`, `sex` and etc witout duplicate values in any columns other than `ID`, you will get what you want.

Comment: I've cleaned up my comments and edited your answer to remove all the wrong stuff - no need to leave it around for posterity. A couple notes: (a) Most any function that has a `...` argument (like `unique()` does) will silently ignore unused arguments. This is very common. (b) Having `summarize` return more than one value was deprecated about a year ago in `dplyr` version 1.1.0. If you run this code in a current version you will get a warning about it (suggesting you use `reframe()` instead), and in an upcoming release this will probably be hard-deprecated and cause errors.

Comment: I think the much better answer is what Axeman suggested in the top comment on the question: `distinct()`. On the `mtcars` example, `distinct(mtcars, cyl, gear)` is a much cleaner way to get where you are going.